# How to combine two activerecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Lets say we have `Event` model, and `SearchEngine` class which performs searches on events.

`SearchEngine` has `search` method.

```
class SearchEngine
  def search(event_scope)
    return Event.all if event_scope.nil?
    //event_scope combined with Event.where('name = ?','test')
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to pass event_scope like this:

```
SearchEngine.new.search(Event.where('start_time > ?',Time.now))
```

And the result would be the same as:

```
Event.where('start_time > ?',Time.now).where('name = ?','test')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just put that query inside search? Why bother with the scope at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scopes provide a [`merge` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) to merge with another scope, so this should work:

```
class SearchEngine
  def search(event_scope)
    return Event.all if event_scope.nil?
    Event.where('name = ?','test').merge(event_scope)
  end
end
```